# Unable to open jigsaw Toxic dataset train and test csv files in WEKA

Tags: weka

I am using WEKA for the first time to do the classification using machine learning models. I tried to open the csv files from the jigsaw toxic dataset downloaded from the attached link:

While opening file, I am getting the following error:

train.csv is not recognized as an 'CSV data files' file.

Reason:
wrong number of values. Read 2, expected 8, read token[EOL], line 2 Problem encountered on line: 2

Before posting this question, I read the answers where it is suggested to replace single quotes and double quotes with blank spaces in the data. I did the same, even removing '\n' didn't solve my problem. For removing '\n', I typed \n in the find box and replaced it with a blank space in libre calc.

[Dataset Link](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/julian3833/jigsaw-toxic-comment-classification-challenge).

Answer (score 0):

Weka's CSV loader is a bit unique and, e.g., cannot handle cells with new lines, it requires them to be escaped as `\n`.

You can install the [common-csv](https://github.com/fracpete/common-csv-weka-package) (unofficial) Weka package, which offers loaders/savers for more common CSV file formats.

Once installed, you can load the toxic CSV files in the Weka Explorer using the "Common CSV files (*.csv)" file type.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I downloaded common-csv folder and extracted the same in the weka folder. My weka version is 3.9.6 but still unable to open it.

Comment: i tried to use the package manager but getting the following errors:java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "weka.core.packageManagement.Package.getPackageMetaDataElement(Object)" because "toLoad" is null
 at weka.core.WekaPackageLibIsolatingClassLoader.checkForNativeLibs(WekaPackageLibIsolatingClassLoader.java:220) there are more errors list after this

Comment: You need to download the release zip file and install that through the package manager (unofficial l/file button). Are you using Weka 3.9.x?

Comment: I did the same using Package Manager. Yes, I am using weak 3.9.x

Comment: Using a fresh Weka 3.9.6 installation and no other packages installed apart from common-csv, I don't get any exceptions (running Linux Mint, Java 11). Maybe the problem is caused by another package? Close Weka, rename the $HOME/wekafiles or %USERPROFILE%\wekafiles folder, restart Weka, reinstall the common-csv package and then check whether Weka starts up.